# unable to iterate through json array from $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, razor

I am facing some problem in assigning data to div on my view page.
The code is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/api/Flight/SearchFlight",
  type: "Post",
  data: $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({
    'TokenId': $("#pageInitCounter").val()
  }, true),
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $('#responsestatus').text(data.Response);
    $('#divResult').html(data);
  });
```

Here, as you can see, I can see the whole data in alert box. also, I have assigned the whole data to div and i can see whole data perfectly on my page.
The Sample Response which i got back is a huge data so i am posting link for it  http://pastebin.com/eEE72ySk

Now I want to iterate through each and every data but unable to do it.
Example:

```
 $('#responsestatus').text(data.Response.ResponseStatus);
```

Then error is:

> UncaughtTypeError:Cannot read property 'ResponseStatus' of undefined

Please Someone tell me what is wrong here. Why cant I iterate over data in response

Comment: You are probably getting the data as a string, not as a json object. Try adding dataType: 'json' to the ajax request. Or use data = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: @Adder Tried as u said ` $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "/api/Flight/SearchFlight",
                        type: "Post",
                         dataType: "json",` tried this but still same error and yes u r right i think i am getting back data as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting your response back as a string, but trying to operate on it like it were a javascript object.

There is one of two things you could do

1. Tell the server you're expecting json data back
2. Parse the string response to json after it is received.

---

The first should be as simple as setting the `datatype` property on the request

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/api/Flight/SearchFlight",
  type: "Post",
  datatype: 'json',
  data: $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({
    'TokenId': $("#pageInitCounter").val()
  }, true),
  success: function(data) {
    $('#responsestatus').text(data.Response.ResponseStatus);
  });
```

The second involves parsing the response before using it

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/api/Flight/SearchFlight",
  type: "Post",
  data: $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({
    'TokenId': $("#pageInitCounter").val()
  }, true),
  success: function(data) {
    var result = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#responsestatus').text(result.Response.ResponseStatus);

  });
```

Comment: Exactly json.parse trick done the job very big thank to u sir @Jamiec

Answer (score 2):

Use Json datatype..i wrote a sample here..

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```